# Customise odoo 12 dashboard

Tags: forms, odoo, dashboard

I am creating dashboard in that I want show form view. the code for dashboard is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
<!-- Action for survey-->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="survey_create_action">
<field name="name">survey.create</field>
<field name="res_model">survey.survey</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">form</field>
<field name="view_id" ref="survey.survey_form"/>

</record>


<!-- board form view -->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="board_form" >
<field name="name">Surveys</field>
<field name="model">board.board</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="survey_page_questions">
<h1>Survey</h1>
<hpaned>
<child1>
<action string="Survey" name="%(survey_create_action)d"/>
<button type="action" name="%(survey.survey_form)d"/>
</child1>
</hpaned>
</form>
</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="board_action">
<field name="name">survey.action</field>
<field name="res_model">board.board</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">form</field>
<field name="usage">menu</field>
<field name="view_id" ref="board_form"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="survey_menu" name="Survey" />
<menuitem id="survey_menu_form" name="survey" parent="survey_menu" action="board_action"/>

</odoo>
```

after loading survey menu nothing will display. also I have create button on dashboard after click on button I want display form view but it gives me following error:

> File "/usr/local/sampada/survey-workspace/spn/odoo/models.py", line
>   2780, in read
>       self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)   File "/usr/local/sampada/survey-workspace/spn/odoo/models.py", line 2959,
>   in _read_from_database
>       forbidden = missing.exists()   File "/usr/local/sampada/survey-workspace/spn/odoo/models.py", line 4319,
>   in exists
>       self._cr.execute(query, [tuple(ids)])   File "/usr/local/sampada/survey-workspace/spn/odoo/sql_db.py", line 148, in
>   wrapper
>       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/sampada/survey-workspace/spn/odoo/sql_db.py", line 225, in
>   execute
>       res = self._obj.execute(query, params) psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "board_board" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT id FROM
>   "board_board" WHERE id IN (false)
>                          ^

why this is happen? any help is appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0):

`relation "board_board" does not exist`

This error means `board_board` table is not available in the database. Whenever a module is installed, models defined in that particular is installed creates corresponding tables in the database, for `board.board` model in this case, `board_board` table must exist. The table not found may be caused by one of the followings:

> => Module not installed properly, install/re-install/upgrade
>
> => `models/__init__.py` file doesn't import the `xxx.py` file that defines the model definition

After the module is imported, check for the `Debug => Settings => Technical => Models` list and search if your particular model is listed or not.

Comment: Thank you @arryph for your soltuion. I have check all cases that you told me. but error is same.  also I am checking in database where relation is not created in database. but going to Debug => Settings => Technical => Models board.board is available.

Comment: Do share your models definition code as this error is directly related to models.

Comment: I haven't created any model . I am try to use board model of odoo.